# Generating a joint probabilities matrix with R with specified conditions

Tags: r, matrix, probability, mean, standard-deviation

I want to generate a matrix 100*100 of joint probabilities P(AiAj) such that the mean of all the probabilities is equal to 0.3 and with a standard deviation of 10%. Is there any function which can directly give me the desired results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Your matrix

```
prob_matrix<-matrix(rnorm(10000,mean=0.3,sd=0.1),nrow=100,ncol=100)
```

The mean

```
mean(prob_matrix)
[1] 0.2999023
```

The standard deviation

```
sd(prob_matrix)
[1] 0.1001522
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't respond to the common probabilities matrix characteristics. Actually, when i apply check.commonprob(prob_matrix) it shows a lot of errors. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bindata/versions/0.9-19/topics/check.commonprob